# Get element next to kendo widget in CSS

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-validator

Can I get the element next to a kendo widget? With normal inputs it works very well but the kendo widget got an parent element before the input Element so it dosen't work.

Example in kendo Dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/apiVejuY/7

I think the problem is my css Selector:

```
.k-textbox.k-valid + label{
  color:green;
}
```

1. Works fine

```
.k-header .k-input.k-valid + label{
  color:green;
}
```

2. Don't work at all. The idea behind this one was to get the complete widget, then look if the input in this widget is valid by kendo. If it is change the label next to the widget.

The question is how do I have to change my second css selector so it works as expected?

Comment: i do not see a .k-header class in the html you provided

Comment: the k-header class is added by default to kendo widget elements (Look with the chrome Devtools there you can see it)

Comment: yeah, well, dunno about that, remove the k-header class in your css sheet and it works

Comment: Hmm can you show me the dojo with the working example when i remove the k-header class its not working for me...

Comment: https://dojo.telerik.com/apiVejuY/9

Comment: type the text, click outside the input box, it turns green

Comment: wait, I misunderstood something, I see now the problem, looking for a solution

Comment: Ohh good i was thinking i am an ape because i didnt get your solution working neither :D. I am looking for a solution too. if the question is hard to read feel free to edit it :)

Comment: What you really need here is a parent selector, which unfortunately CSS doesn't currently possess. The simplest solution to this problem would probably be to hook the validator's `validateInput` event and manipulate the label from javascript.